# Replace string matching a pattern with it's value, but differently formatted

Tags: php, regex, mybb

I have a function on my mybb that displays the date of the last post: $lastpostdate

Function prints values in this format: 01-27-2016, 12:31 am

I need this to be displayed otherwise, but I don't want to modify the function itself, because it's being used in multiple places on the webpage - where the original format suits me.

So basically I need something working like this:

1. get $lastpostdate value
2. present it in a different form

I was thinking of making a conditional (so in a specific place, the date format would be different) looking somewhat like this:

```
if ($lastpostdate = regex match(original form))
{
 print($lastpostdate but in different form);
}
```

I actually just need to make this:

```
$lastpostdate='<span>01-27-2016, 12:31 am</span>';
```

Into this:

```
$lastpostdate_after='<span>01-27-2016,<br />12:31 am</span>';
```

I guess it should be easier to clone the function and adjust the format in it and then use the custom form.

I can use only PHP.

**Solved:**

**A plugin is required in order to add php into templates: [PHP and Template Conditionals (2.1) by ZiNgA BuRgA](http://mybbhacks.zingaburga.com/showthread.php?tid=260)**

**Replace {$lastpostdate} with:**

```
<?php 
    $input=$lastpostdate;
    $output =str_replace(',', ',<br />', $input);
    print($output);
?>
```

This is not a conditional.

Comment: preg_replace_callback() with a callback that does the reformatting

Comment: You want to add a newline after a comma? `str_replace` the comma with a comma+linebreak. [`$res = str_replace(",",",\n\n","01-27-2016, 12:31 am");`](http://ideone.com/bbWytR).

Comment: Well it'd have to be a <br /> tag, but that shouldn't be a problem. I'm just new to the whole thing and I gotta catch how to use all those functions. And of course the dates are variables, so I can't replace things with fixed value (unless it's taken from the variable :D)

Comment: You could use the variable and apply the `str_replace()`; to that, just replacing the comma with `,<br />` and linebreaks. (A comma to replace the one you are replacing and linebreaks to keep your HTML tidy.)

Comment: You're right! That's actually making it very easy, because the comma will always be there. When I'll be at my desk I'll check this out. Thanks!

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew gave you the original structure - change his text date to `$lastpostdate` and make `,\n\n` into `,<br /><br />\n\n` and that should give you the double linespacing with well formatted HTML Good luck!